# AngularJS using service to pass data without $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I started using angularjs and the first examples i saw were ones that use `this` instead of `$scope`.

for example

```
app.controller('TabController',function(){
    this.tab = 1;
});
```

I am trying to pass data between controllers. every example i see uses a service that is using `$rootScope` and then broadcast an event. the controller then uses the `$scope.$on` to listen to that event.

for example

```
app.service('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.tab = 1;    

    sharedService.setTab= function(tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});

app.controller('TabController',['$scope','mySharedService',function($scope,mySharedService){
    $scope.tab = 1;
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.tab = sharedService.tab;
    });
}]);
```

my question is how do i do this without using `$scope` but instead using `this`.

Comment: You should inject your service inside the controller and consume it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xtaDF5FQtz99dbl1ZI3x?p=preview see this plunk I've set up for you.

Comment: Using this doesn't prevent you from using $scope, $rootScope, or both.

Comment: @JBNizet look at Dieter comment

Comment: @yossi that is fine, but it doesn't allow notifying a controller when the data in the service has changed, and that is usually the reason why an event is broadcasted.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree, but if you just want to share data an event is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @Dieter Goetelen answer and changed it a bit

the result:

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('SharedService',function(){
  this.counter = {value:0};
  this.add = function (amount){ 
       this.counter.value++;}
  });

app.controller('TabController',['SharedService',function(SharedService){
    this.sharedService = SharedService;
    this.counter = SharedService.counter;

    this.add = function(amount){
        this.sharedService.add(amount);
     }    
}]);
```

here is the complete [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZBOKeTXLFNl06klerwZ?p=preview)

Comment: Glad I could help you find a solution.